# Swing not Drawing in Applet

Tags: java, swing, applet

I have to program a breakout game for school and I ran into a problem. I need to paint my 2D figures but I can't see them.

This is my applet. test() is a JPanel which I will link below.

```
public class Gamefield extends Applet{

test t;


@Override
public void init() {
    t = new test();
    setSize(1600, 900);

    Frame frame = (Frame)this.getParent().getParent();
    frame.setTitle("Breakout");



    add(t);
}
}
```

Here is my JPanel where I call repaint().

```
public class test extends JPanel implements Runnable {



public test(){

    setSize(1600,900);


    Thread thread = new Thread(this);
    thread.start();
}

@Override
public void run() {
    while(true){
        System.out.println("a");
        try{
            repaint();
            Thread.sleep(1000/60);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    System.out.println("draw");
    super.paintComponents(g);
    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g.drawOval(500,500,100,100);
    g.fillRect(100,100,100,100);
}

}
```

I hope that someone can help me out. I don't know what I can try to fix it.

Comment: 1) Why code an applet?  If it is due to the teacher specifying it, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should **stop** teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/).  Note also that the Swing applet is `javax.swing.JApplet`.. 2) For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example).

Comment: It is easier to do animation in Swing using a `Timer` to call `repaint()`..

Comment: Well still.. It's not showing the rectangle.. Is it because of the applet thingy.. Should I convert to JFrame?

Comment: *"It's not showing the rectangle.."*  For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example).

Comment: Okay, give me a minute.. Will work out an MCVE

Comment: Okay I edited the code to a minimal version

Comment: How is that 'minimal'?  I'd bet you can remove 1) Setting the size of the applet. 2) Setting the name of the applet viewer, and 3) All those empty overridden methods and still see the problem.  -- Also, does it fail if the threading code is removed?

Comment: It's minimal, because if you copy paste this in your IDE, it'll work without having errors about not having certain classes..

I left the settings because these don't really matter and they are how I got them local, plus the repaint uses the XY coordinate system.. So I provide a size which should be big enough so you can clearly see the problem. The overridden stuff are needed because it's an applet.

Comment: *"It's minimal, because if you copy paste this in your IDE, it'll work without having errors.."*  That is not what 'minimal' means.  And I should know, since I made the first draft of the MCVE document.  See the MCVE in my answer for 'minimal'.  All the cruft and irrelevant crap is removed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class GameField extends JApplet {

    @Override
    public void init() {
        // Applet is FlowLayout by default, which does not stretch components
        // let's use GridLayout instead
        setLayout(new GridLayout()); 
        add(new test());
    }
}

class test extends JPanel {

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        System.out.println("draw");
        // super.paintComponents(g);  // WRONG method!  Broken paint chain
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.drawOval(500, 500, 100, 100);
        g.fillRect(100, 100, 100, 100);
    }
}
```

Comment: OMG, Thanks, It seems that it was the setLayout fixed the problem. Changed the Super.paintComponent(g) because it is indeed wrong.

Thank you, One small question, should I still convert to JFrame if possible or keep on working in Applet?

Comment: Well, let's put it this way.  I ***wrote*** that blog article denouncing applets that I linked to earlier.  And as it mentions in the article, I am the 'top' provider of answers for the `Applet` (& `JApplet`) tags.

Comment: Oh, and if you really need to distribute to others from the net, see [Java Web Start](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).

Comment: You know what, I'll work out an JFrame version, because I follow your thoughts, I'll let my teacher read it and maybe he'll grant me permission. Thanks for everything.

Comment: If he does not grant you permission he needs sacking IMO.  Best of luck with it, and I'd love to know the result.